# get_collector_list request in java

Tags: surveymonkey

trying the request  by passing the surveyID as a parameter from java using following input string. 
 Getting following **error**

```
{"status": 3, "errmsg": "No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)"}
```

`String input ="{\"survey_id\": p_sSurveyID, \"fields\":[\"url\"]}";`  -- not working

where as same is working fine if the surveyID is hard coded

`String input ="{\"survey_id\":\"12345678\", \"fields\":[\"url\"]}";`  -- working

Comment: Your question is not very clear? Where are you trying this? which language?What platform?

Comment: Something is up with your value for `p_sSurveyID`.

Comment: I am trying this in JAVA.    Yes I have assigned a value for p_sSurveyID

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not concatenating the psSurveyID properly.

```
String input ="{\"survey_id\": p_sSurveyID, \"fields\":[\"url\"]}"; -- not working
```

should be

```
String input ="{\"survey_id\":"+ p_sSurveyID+",\"fields\":[\"url\"]}"; -- should work


  System.out.println("p_sSurveyID --- " + p_sSurveyID); 
  try 
  { 
      List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      parameters.add(new NameValuePair("api_key",p_sApiKey));
      URL url = new URL(createUrl(BASE_URL+COLLECTOR_LIST_ENDPOINT,parameters));     
      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
      conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "bearer "+p_sAuthToken);



     String input ="{\"survey_id\":"+ p_sSurveyID+",\"fields\":[\"url\"]}"; 
     OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
     os.write(input.getBytes());
     os.flush();
     if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
     throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " +conn.getResponseCode()); 
      }
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReString input ="{\"survey_id\":"+ p_sSurveyID+",\"fields\":[\"url\"]}"; 
     OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
     os.write(input.getBytes()); os.flush();
     if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
     throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + 
     conn.getResponseCode()); 

      }
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( (conn.getInputStream())));



    conn.disconnect();
    ader(new InputStreamReader( (conn.getInputStream()))); 
    conn.disconnect();
```

Comment: Hi thanks very much for you answer with String input ="{\"survey_id\":"+ p_sSurveyID+",\"fields\":[\"url\"]}";

Comment: Hi thanks very much for you answer with String input ="{\"survey_id\":"+ p_sSurveyID+",\"fields\":[\"url\"]}"; getting following error message {"status": 3, "errmsg": "Value 45931029 for field 'survey_id' is not of type string"}

Comment: .
.
private final static String SURVEY_ID = "12345678";

.
.
.
public static void main(String[] args) {

      getSurveyList(APP_ID, "myaccesstoken"));

     getCollectorList(SURVEY_ID, APP_ID, "myaccesstoken"));
     
    }
.
.
.

 public static String getCollectorList(String p_sSurveyID, String p_sApiKey, String p_sAuthToken){

     String output="";
     System.out.println("in Collectors list");
     System.out.println("p_sSurveyID --- " + p_sSurveyID);

Comment: System.out.println("p_sSurveyID --- " + p_sSurveyID); 
     try {
      
      List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      
      parameters.add(new NameValuePair("api_key",p_sApiKey));
      URL url = new URL(createUrl(BASE_URL+COLLECTOR_LIST_ENDPOINT,parameters));
      
      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setDoOutput(true);
      conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "bearer "+p_sAuthToken);

Comment: String input ="{\"survey_id\":"+ p_sSurveyID+",\"fields\":[\"url\"]}"; 
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
      os.write(input.getBytes());
      os.flush();

      if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
         + conn.getResponseCode());
      }
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (conn.getInputStream())));
     

      
         conn.disconnect();
-- exception handling
     }      return output;
    }

Comment: Hi  String input ="{\"survey_id\":"+ p_sSurveyID+",\"fields\":[\"url\"]}"; -- should work
here the survey_id is getting replaced with the value but its considering as a String.